# Increase and Decrease font size of selected/Highlighted text inside the iframe tag using jquery in google chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I used the `execCommand()` to increase and decrease the font size of selected/highlighted text (while we click the increment or decrement button the selected text font size is increased or decreased by 2px).

`execCommand()` is working perfectly in Mozilla Firefox, but it is not working in Google Chrome. How can I "Increase and Decrease font size of selected/Highlighted text inside the iframe tag using jquery in google chrome browser"?

Comment: Here is my code
function fontEditor(fontName) {
 rte.document.execCommand("fontName", false,fontName);                                                                                        }

<input type="button" value="Inc"  onclick="rte.document.execCommand ('increaseFontSize')" style="position:absolute;left:500px;top:0px;">
  <input type="button" value="Dec" onclick="rte.document.execCommand ('decreaseFontSize')" style="position:absolute;left:533px;top:0px;">

Comment: Thank you  Alexander Dayan. your code is working perfectly....

Comment: It's my pleasure to help :) Could you please accept my answer?

Comment: Yes,I accept your answer......
              once again thanks a lot......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, FontSize is limited by the standard values from 1 to 7 intepreted as 'xx-small', 'x-small', 'small', 'medium', 'large', 'x-large' and 'xx-large' consequently:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var fontSize = 3;
  
  $('#decrease').click(function(){
    if (fontSize > 1)
      fontSize--;
    document.execCommand("fontSize", false, fontSize);
  });
  
  $('#increase').click(function(){
    if (fontSize < 7)
      fontSize++;
    document.execCommand("fontSize", false, fontSize);
  });
})
```

```css
div{
  margin-top: 16px;
  padding: 4px;
  border: solid 1px gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='decrease' type="button" value="Decrease Font">
<input id='increase' type="button" value="Increase Font">
<div contenteditable="true">Hello, this is some editable text</div>
```

You can customize this functionality by using a hacky method which calls `document.execCommand("fontSize", false, "1")`, finds the elements and changes it:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var fontSize = 16;
  
  $('#decrease').click(function(){
    if (fontSize > 6)
      fontSize-=2;
    document.execCommand("fontSize", false, "1");
    resetFont();
  });
  
  $('#increase').click(function(){
    if (fontSize < 64)
      fontSize+=2;
    document.execCommand("fontSize", false, "1");
    resetFont();
  });
  
  function resetFont(){
    $("font[size=1]").removeAttr("size").css("font-size", fontSize + "px");
  }
})
```

```css
div{
  margin-top: 16px;
  padding: 4px;
  border: solid 1px gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='decrease' type="button" value="Decrease Font">
<input id='increase' type="button" value="Increase Font">
<div contenteditable="true">Hello, this is some editable text</div>
```

Remark: the above code samples are written for contenteditable div, but conceptually it;s no difference with iframe-based editor.